# Using block rom to store image values in fpga

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I want to get image values and then process this image with my fpga board. But I couldn't import the values of image. I searched block rom usage about it but couldn't find any tutorial or something. How can I import image values? Board is Zynq-7000/verilog/xilinx. Thanks.

Comment: The size of the image (in bytes, not in height width) is important. You might have a look at a Xilinx application about initializing memory blocks. I tested image processing by uploading (big) images to the Zync DDR memory. (But I am off to bed now).

Comment: 50x50, small size

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dump raw bytes from the image, in whatever way you will find convenient, and use some third-party tools ([like this one](https://wornwinter.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/coegen-v0-01-generate-coe-files-from-binary-files-for-xilinx-fpga-block-ram/)) to create COE file that you will use with the core generator for memory initialization.

It seems Xilinx tools doesn't support COE file creation on its own, even from existing binary data.